# django rest framework saving M2M relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a cart with a m2m relationship, on saving this object the serializer raises two weird exceptions and if i changed the relation to one to many, everything works fine!.

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `quantity` on serializer `ItemSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `BranchItemList` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'BranchItemList' object has no attribute 'quantity'.
>
> AttributeError at /api/carts/29
>   Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `item_list` on serializer `ItemSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `BranchItemList` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'BranchItemList' object has no attribute 'item_list'.

My input:

```
{
    "items":[
        {"item_list":350,"price":10,"quantity":20},
        {"item_list":300,"price":10,"quantity":20}
        ]
}
```

Models:

[image]

Serializers:

[image]

Comment: replace your images with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `through` model for M2M, you actualy need `ItemCart` model in serializer, but Cart's `items` M2M manager return `BranchItemList`. To fix error specify `source='itemcart_set'`:

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = ItemSerializer(source='itemcart_set', many=True)
```

Comment: actually you made my day, but i tried something weird, i turned on the debugger to trace the problem and every time  the code runs in debugging mode it works fine as expected, and after switching to development mode it fails.